# Returning a 2D array in the response from controller .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

So, im trying to do a .Net Core Web API and an Angular front that resembles a 2d Game. The back-end generates a 2-dimensional string array that maps to certain set of tiles. However i found out that you apparently can't return a 2D array in the response.

Here are my models:

```
public class ResponseWrapper<T>
{
    // this is my response wrapper
    public string message { get; set; }
    public T body { get; set; }
}

public class FieldGrid{
    // this model has the 2D array that is going to represent my tiles
    public String[,] FieldGridArray { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FieldMatrixController : ControllerBase
{
    private IGenerateField _genF;
    public FieldMatrixController(IGenerateField genF) {
        _genF = genF;
    }

    [HttpGet("{rows}/{columns}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> testCall(int rows, int columns) {

        ResponseWrapper<FieldGrid> Response = new ResponseWrapper<FieldGrid>();
        // this method creates a new FieldGrid and fills it with strings that are going to be mapped to my tiles, i used the debugger to make sure they are properly filled
        FieldGrid fGrid = _genF.GenerateFieldGrid(rows, columns);
        Response.body = fGrid;
        Response.message = "Howdy :D";

        return Ok(Response);
    }

}
```

Everything seems to be working until i send the request from my browser and i get the following error: `NotSupportedException: The collection type 'System.String[,]' on 'back_octo_adventure.Models.FieldMatrix.FieldGrid.FieldGridArray' is not supported.`

Apparently .net core is missing a few features from their new Json serializer in 3.0 or something like that. My issue is that i need a 2D array in the response and i'm not entirely sure what to do now.

Comment: Json only has a 1d array type. Though it should be possible to return an array of arrays. Perhaps you could cast it to an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`?

Comment: Basically you can switch to JSON.Net serializer, but better return type that is natively supported by JSON as @JeremyLakeman suggested. (I picked a duplicate that says "no 2d arrays not supported in JSON", not sure if that is enough for you to get the answer - if something is still unclear - [edit] the question...)

Comment: Side note: multidimensional arrays in .Net/C# are generally pain to deal with and switching to `List<List<MyCellClass>>` could make things easier in general for your code.

Comment: I oficially hate 2D arrays in c#. I was wondering why arrays are like [,] instead of [][]. Thx, gonna try both, the array of arrays, or list of lists thing. Also i wasn't aware that Json doesn't have 2d arrays per se, and more like arrays of arrays, just assumed they were the same xD.